# How to place banner ad on top of App Bar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, appbar, banner-ads

How can I place a banner ad on the top of the top App Bar in Flutter? I have the banner ad at the bottom of the bottom app bar as shown below. I want to move it to the top, so that it becomes the first widget of the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PreferredSize](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PreferredSize-class.html) or [flexibleSpace](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar/flexibleSpace.html),

###### PreferredSize

```
appBar: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(120), // change height of ads as you like
    child: Container(
        child: // here is ads
    )
)
```

or

###### flexibleSpace

```
appBar: AppBar(
    toolbarHeight: 120, // Set this appbar height
    flexibleSpace: Container(
        child: Text("this is add"),  // make container of your ads
    ),
    title: Text('Material App Bar'),
),
```

Answer (score 2):

Try preferredSizeAppbar widget and increase the app bar height and use you banner.